# I can't clicking on the label button with javascripts

Tags: python, selenium

I have 1 question that I can't clicking on the button with javascript.
I use

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='login']/a")
```

but it doesn't work at all.
it seems like javascripts.

[image]

Plz help me to clicking on the login button.

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get?. As already asked share more HTML code.

Comment: self = <PageObjects.Login_Page.Login object at 0x10983fd90>
driver = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="8106a10bff4c3223c8852a52e8fb7584")>

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
    
>       self.lnkLogin = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Login_Locator.loginLnk)
E       AttributeError: type object 'Login_Locator' has no attribute 'loginLnk'

../../PageObjects/Login_Page.py:8: AttributeError

Comment: sourcecode is here


class LoginPage(BaseSetup):

    def test_LoginPage(self):

        driver = self.driver
        # driver.get("https://www.oliveyoung.co.kr")
        login = Login_Page.Login(driver)

        login.loginTxtLink().click()

        login.getEmail().send_keys(TestData.email)
        login.getPassword().send_keys(TestData.password)
        login.loginBtn().click()

        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Comment: Update the same in the question.

Comment: @pmadhu what do you mean?

Comment: Update the question with the code and the error. Dont comment it.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This might be more helpful if you can provide more of the source code or maybe a link to the site?

But from what I see. Did you actually click?

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='login']/a").click()
```

Comment: Yeah, I did. but It doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the element to be clickable (remember to add proper imports), and here is a working code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.oliveyoung.co.kr")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='login']/a"))).click()
input()
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//li[@class='login']//a
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This div is not under an iframe.
2. This div is not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

if it matches the desired element, then in Selenium there are 4 ways to click on it.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='login']//a").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='login']//a"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='login']//a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='login']//a")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```